# Отсутствие соединения на хостинге

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Добрый день. Разрабатываю сайт на CMS Pagekit. В состав включены Symfony и ORM Doctrine.
При отсутствии соединения с бд хостинга сие чудо смело выводит всю инфу о подключении к базе. (Debug mode выключен)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
/..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace: #0 /..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/
PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'user', 'password', Array)
#1 /..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/
Driver.php(44): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...',
'user', 'password', Array)
#2 /..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): 
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'user', 'password', Array) #3 
/..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(833): 
Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() #4 /..patch to cms../app/modules/database/ in 
/..patch to cms../app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
on line 115
```

Кто сталкивался, как отловить это исключение и выводить страницу с ошибкой вместо этого?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    ...
}
catch(PDOException){
    print "База данных не доступна\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Само собой синтаксис php я знаю. Вопрос был в том где это вписать в файлах Doctrine.

Answer (score -1):

Да уж, я думал тут ответят мгновенно. В общем если кто столкнется, выключайте ошибки в php.ini и будет вам счастье.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]